# Can't Get NodeJs App to work on Openshift

Tags: node.js, mongodb, openshift

I'm trying to get a simple nodejs app hosted on Openshift. This is the repo:
https://github.com/ndevilla511/mean-trail-blog

And here is the log from the pod where the app runs.

```
Environment: 
DEV_MODE=false
NODE_ENV=production
DEBUG_PORT=5858
Launching via npm...
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@3.10.9
npm info using node@v6.9.1
npm info lifecycle MEAN-trail-blog@4.0.0-alpha~prestart: MEAN-trail-
blog@4.0.0-alpha
npm info lifecycle MEAN-trail-blog@4.0.0-alpha~start: MEAN-trail-blog@4.0.0-
alpha

node app.js

Magic happens on port 8080
Db.prototype.authenticate method will no longer be available in the next 
major release 3.x as MongoDB 3.6 will only allow auth against users in the 
admin db and will no longer allow multiple credentials on a socket. Please a 
authenticate using MongoClient.connect with auth credentials.
Mongoose connected to mongodb://admin:password@mongodb/meanblog
```

It looks like the server is listening on port 8080 and is able to connect with the MongoDB database I have set up in the same project on Openshift.
I've already exposed a route for it, but when I go to the link, I get a 503 and a page that says the Application is Unavailable. Just need help to get pointed in the right direction

Comment: Is this your own Docker image, or are you using the NodeJS S2I builder provided with OpenShift?

Comment: This is my own docker image, not the one provided.

Comment: It would help to see your ``Dockerfile`` to verify you have an appropriate ``EXPOSE`` statement. Also, have you tried getting into the container and used curl to connect to port 8080 via localhost and via ``$HOSTNAME``.